# formatting a table using KableExtra

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

trying to create a table with a set of data from an excel sheet. the table comes out fine, however i keep seeing a replication of the column name. especially when numerical data is used. for example it continues to repeat station 1 as station 1....2 and station 2 as station 2...3 as below
[this is what the output looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUJ7e.png)

here is the code i ran

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
LAGOS_SHIP_CHANNEL <- read_excel("C:/Users/missw/Desktop/903 -/LAGOS SHIP CHANNEL.xlsx", 
    sheet = "dry _wet seasn")
dt <- LAGOS_SHIP_CHANNEL
kbl(dt, caption = "Monthly composition of zooplankton per ml at Lagos Ship Channel, Southwest Nigeria (Nov. 2021- Aug. 2022)", booktabs = T) %>%
row_spec(row = 1:13, italic = TRUE) %>%
row_spec(18:19, bold = T)  %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position")) %>%
kable_classic() %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1,"Dry season" = 7, "Wet season" = 7))
```
````

this was the result.

```
> library(kableExtra)
> library(readxl)
> options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
> LAGOS_SHIP_CHANNEL <- read_excel("C:/Users/missw/Desktop/903 -/LAGOS SHIP CHANNEL.xlsx", 
+     sheet = "dry _wet seasn")
New names:
> dt <- LAGOS_SHIP_CHANNEL
> kbl(dt, caption = "Monthly composition of zooplankton per ml at Lagos Ship Channel, Southwest Nigeria (Nov. 2021- Aug. 2022)", booktabs = T) %>%
+ row_spec(row = 1:13, italic = TRUE) %>%
+ row_spec(18:19, bold = T)  %>%
+ kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position")) %>%
+ kable_classic() %>%
+ add_header_above(c(" " = 1,"Dry season" = 7, "Wet season" = 7))
```

my problem is when i knit to pdf, "new names" is also displayed in the pdf. the output shows a repition of the column values -

what i expect as output was

station 1 , station 2, station 3, station 4

Comment: Try to add `col_names = TRUE` to the `read_excel()` command.

Comment: thanks  @julian for the response  i tried that. still not resolved .